# Disk Space Check in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am currently checking disk space size using power shell but was wondering how I can amend the below to add a percentage of space left?

```
Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1MB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1MB,2)}}
```

I have tried to do it by changing the math but no luck.

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk  -Computername PCNAME| Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1MB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace" (%);e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100,2)}}|Out-File c:\PMC\Disk\OutPut\Newcastle.txt
```

This just returns an error.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Format-Table` in a `ForEach-Object` block or `foreach` loop.

Comment: Any ideas on the actual question though @Bill_Stewart

Comment: Use math. percent free =  free space / total space.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to do it:

```
gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | select Name, FileSystem,FreeSpace,BlockSize,Size | % {$_.BlockSize=(($_.FreeSpace)/($_.Size))*100;$_.FreeSpace=($_.FreeSpace/1GB);$_.Size=($_.Size/1GB);$_}| Format-Table Name, @{n='FS';e={$_.FileSystem}},@{n='Free, Gb';e={'{0:N2}'-f
$_.FreeSpace}}, @{n='Free,%';e={'{0:N2}'-f $_.BlockSize}} -AutoSize
```

output:

```
Name FS   Free, Gb Free,%
---- --   -------- ------
C:   NTFS 593.59   31.88
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of a script I have written that may help you:

```
If (Test-Path 'C:')
{
    $CDisk = GWMI Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"
    $CDisk = @{'Size'      = [Math]::Round($CDisk.Size / 1GB);
               'FreeSpace' = [Math]::Round($CDisk.FreeSpace / 1GB)}
    $CDisk.Add('Usage', ($CDisk.Size - $CDisk.FreeSpace))
    $CDisk.Add('PercentUsage', [Math]::Round(($CDisk.Usage / $CDisk.Size) * 100))

    "C: drive free space: $($CDisk.FreeSpace)GB"
    "C: drive capacity:   $($CDisk.Size)GB"
    '--------------------------------'
    "Disk usage:          $($CDisk.Usage)GB ($($CDisk.PercentUsage)%)"
}
```